# Swift: Change values of objects in GameScene.swift from other class

Tags: ios, swift, class, viewcontroller

I work on a SpriteKit Game which is connected to another Device via MultipeerConnectivity. I put all the Connection stuff in an extra ConnectionManager.swift file to clean up the code a bit.

When receiving data, a function in the ConnectionManager.swift class is called to convert the data into Float and pass the value to a function in the GameScene.swift class.

---

GameViewController.swift:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
  }
}
```

---

GameScene.swift:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()    
let ConnectionsManager = ConnectionManager()

 func dummyText(Spieler: Int, Anweisung: Float) {
    print("dummyText")
    scoreLabel.text = String(Anweisung)
 }
```

---

ConnectionManager.swift : Here is the function that should pass values to GameScene().dummyText()

```
class ConnectionManager: NSObject, MCSessionDelegate, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate {

func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    print("Etwas erhalten!")
    NSLog("%@", "Etwas erhalten!")
    // Trying with dummy Value
    GameScene().dummyText(Spieler: 1, Anweisung: 200 )
    }
}
```

---

By using GameScene() I assume that I create a new instance instead of using the GameScene which is already shown and which I want to manipulate. Unfortunately I don't know how to work with different classes correctly. The best resolution for me would be to call the ConnectionManager class as some kind of ChildClass of GameViewController, so I can call functions like super.dummyText().

Besides learning swift for a few weeks I am still a newbie. I searched for this problem for a long time and I found some results, but no resolution worked for me. That's why I am posting a new topic here. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: As you said, the issue is that you're creating a new GameScene() instead of using the one created in your view controller. There are many ways to solve this, including: passing the GameScene instance as a param to your ConnectionManager initializer; creating a custom ConnectionManager delegate that calls back when data is received; registering GameScene with some custom "Game Manager" that owns all of the game-related objects; exposing GameScene as an instance property on your view controller; or even  making GameScene a singleton. The right approach for you depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I made GameScene a singleton now which is finally working as I expected it to do. Thanks!